# Trouble with setting both DataTemplate and ControlTemplate to Map Pushpins in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, bing-maps, pushpin

I am having trouble setting both `DataTemplate` and `ControlTemplate` to my bing map pushpins. I am using data binding which works to a point when i try to customize my pushpins by adding `ControlTemplate`.

My code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BingMap.MapUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF" 
         xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
         xmlns:viewPushpins="clr-namespace:Program.Map_Control.ViewPushpins">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewPushpins:MapViewPushpins/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PushpinDataTemplateP">
        <m:Pushpin Location = "{Binding MapLocationP}" ToolTip="{Binding MapTooltipTextP}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplateP">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Fill="Green" Width="15" Height="15" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <m:Map  Name="myMap"
            CredentialsProvider="..."
            ZoomLevel="1"
            Center="30,-100"
            Mode="AerialWithLabels"
            MouseLeftButtonUp="Map_Left_Click_Up">
        <m:MapItemsControl
            Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplateP}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PushpinDataTemplateP}" MouseLeftButtonUp="Map_Left_Click_Up"
            ItemsSource="{Binding  MapLocationsP}"/>
    </m:Map>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

This code works if I remove the line:

```
Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplateP}"
```

but then don't get my customized pushpin.

Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where i got this wrong. As already mentioned by Kent, the line

```
Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplateP}"
```

shouldn't be in MapItemsControl.

I solved my problem with moving this line of code to Resources so they look like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplateP">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill="Green" Width="15" Height="15" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="PushpinDataTemplateP">
    <m:Pushpin Location = "{Binding MapLocationP}" ToolTip="{Binding MapTooltipTextP}" Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplateP}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting `MapItemsControl.Template`, you're specifying a template for the `MapItemsControl` itself, not the items it produces. You can set the template for individual items produced by an `ItemsControl` indirectly via the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="PushPinStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- your template goes here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<m:MapItemsControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource }" ...>
```